# Todo list на js работа с DOM не работает кнопки

Tags: javascript, html, css

Я новичок, написал ToDo list вчера код работал, а сегодня ничего не пашет, git не пользовался так что не могу откатить назад. А проблема в том что при добавление еще одного li > не работает complete и delete у всех, а у первого элемента работает delete и удаляет все элементы li

```js
// Get Elements
const input = document.getElementById('input');
const clear = document.querySelector('.clear');
const date = document.getElementById('date');
const list = document.getElementById('list');
const item = document.querySelector('.item');

// Variables
let id = 0;

// ToDo Components
function addToDo(){
    id++;
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.classList.add('item');
    list.appendChild(li);
    li.innerHTML = `
            <i class="fa fa-circle-thin co" work="complete" id=${id}></i>
            <p class="text">${input.value}</p>
            <i class="fa fa-trash-o de" del="delete" id=${id}></i>
    `;
    const del = document.querySelector('.de');
    const complete = document.querySelector('.co');
    const text = document.querySelector('.text');
    // Complete element is click in check circle
    complete.addEventListener("click", () => {
        text.classList.toggle('lineThrough');
        const circleThin = complete.classList.contains('fa-circle-thin');
        if(circleThin){
            complete.classList.remove('fa-circle-thin');
            complete.classList.add('fa-check-circle');
        }else{
            complete.classList.remove('fa-check-circle');
            complete.classList.add('fa-circle-thin');
        }
    });

    // Delete element is click in urn
    del.addEventListener("click", () => {
        li.remove();
    });
}

// Date in header
function dateNow(){
    let options = { weekday: 'long', month: 'short', day: 'numeric'};
    let dateToday = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-US', options);
    date.innerText = dateToday;
}
dateNow();

// Clear Listener
clear.addEventListener('click', () => {
    clearList();
});

function clearList(){
    location.reload()
}

// Input listener
input.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        addToDo();
        input.value = '';
    }
});
```

```css
body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

/* ------------ container ------------ */
.container{
    padding:10px;
    width:380px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

/* ------------ header ------------ */
.header{
    width: 380px;
    height:200px;
    background-color: #000;
    background-size: 100% 200%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
    position: relative;
}
.clear{
    width : 30px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    right:20px;
    top: 20px;
}
.clear i{
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #FFF;
}
.clear i:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    text-shadow: 1px 3px 5px #000;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#date{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

/* ------------ content ------------ */
.content{
    width:380px;
    height: 350px;
    max-height:350px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    overflow: auto;
}
.content::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
.content ul{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.item{
    width:380px;
    height: 45px;
    min-height: 45px;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.item i.co{
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding-left:5px;
    left:15px;
    top:10px;
}
.item i.co:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.fa-check-circle{
    color:#6eb200;
}
.item p.text{
    position: absolute;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    font-size: 20px;
    left:50px;
    top:5px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    max-width:285px;
}
.lineThrough{
    text-decoration: line-through;
    color : #ccc;
}
.item i.de{
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 25px;
    right:15px;
    top:10px;
}
.item i.de:hover{
    color:#af0000;
    cursor: pointer;
}
/* ------------ add item ------------ */
.add-to-do{
    position: relative;
    width: 360px;
    height:40px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.add-to-do i{
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #4162f6;
}

.add-to-do input{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    height: 35px;
    width: 310px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left:10px;
}
.add-to-do input::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
    color: #4162f6;
    font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.add-to-do input::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
    color: #4162f6;
    font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.add-to-do input:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
    color: #4162f6;
    font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.add-to-do input:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
    color: #4162f6;
    font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">
    <title>To Do приложение</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="clear">
                <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
            </div>
            <div id="date"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <ul id="list">

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="add-to-do">
            <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
            <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Добавить задачу" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: дело в том, что `document.querySelector('.clear')` возвращает 1-й элемент с классом `clear`. Потому и удаление работает только у него.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, с clear кнопкой все отлично, проблема в том что после добавление задачи 1 элемент <li> работает и все отлично, добавляем еще один элемент <li>, и уже у всех элементов не работает чекбокс(зеленая галочка и зачеркнутый текст), кнопка урны(удалить элемент) тоже не работает после добавление 2-n элементов, но работает у первого элемента, которая при клике удаляет все li элементы.

Comment: с предыдущим комментарием несколько поспешил, но причина та же: нужно исправить `const del = document.querySelector('.de');` (и аналогичные выражения). Ты выбираешь 1-й элемент в документе, а нужно -- в строке. Т.е. слушатель действий ты добавляешь только к первой строке. При этом ссылка на li корректная, потому удаляются все `li`

Comment: Отлично, Спасибо вам!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function addToDo(){
        id++;
        const li = document.createElement('li');
        li.classList.add('item');
        list.appendChild(li);
        li.innerHTML = `
                <i class="fa fa-circle-thin co" work="complete" id=${id}></i>
                <p class="text">${input.value}</p>
                <i class="fa fa-trash-o de" del="delete" id=${id}></i>
        `;
        // Ваша ошибка здесь..
        const del = document.querySelector('.de'); 
        // Вы выбераете первый елемент во всем документе с классом .de
        // Ваш нужно это исправить на 
        // const del = li.querySelector('.de');
        // Ваша ошибка здесь..

        const complete = document.querySelector('.co');
        const text = document.querySelector('.text');
        // Complete element is click in check circle
        complete.addEventListener("click", () => {
            text.classList.toggle('lineThrough');
            const circleThin = complete.classList.contains('fa-circle-thin');
            if(circleThin){
                complete.classList.remove('fa-circle-thin');
                complete.classList.add('fa-check-circle');
            }else{
                complete.classList.remove('fa-check-circle');
                complete.classList.add('fa-circle-thin');
            }
        });

        // Delete element is click in urn
        del.addEventListener("click", () => {
            li.remove();
        });
    }
```